# String similarity algorithm returns false values

Tags: c++, algorithm

I've wrote little piece of code to check string similarity percentage. It looks like that:

```
int similarity(std::string s1, std::string s2) {
    int size = 0, sim = 0;
    if(s1==s2) {
        sim = 100;
    } else {
        if(s1 > s2)
            size = s2.size();
        else
            size = s1.size();

        for(int i = 0; i != (size); ++i) {
            if(s1[i] == s2[i])
                ++sim;
        }
    }
    return (sim/s2.size()>s1.size()?s2.size():s1.size())*10;
}
```

And I test it in main function like that (I've added these 'dddd' to make character amount = 10):

```
std::cout << "Similarity of gananadddd and bananadddd (%): " << std::endl;
std::cout << similarity("gananadddd", "bananadddd") << "%" << std::endl;
```

And console output:

```
Similarity of gananadddd and bananadddd (%):
100%
```

So I think my code doesn't work well because:

- Precentage shouldn't be 100%, because just one letter changed.
- Sometime before I've noticed that for this input percentage could be 1000%, if i would change `return (sim/s2.size()>s1.size()?s2.size():s1.size())*10;` to
  `return (sim/s2.size()>s1.size()?s2.size():s1.size())*100;`. And actually it should be 100!

I would be really happy is someone would point me out where I've made mistake. Also, I can consider changing algorithm

EDIT:

I've modified code a bit:

```
double similarity(std::string s1, std::string s2) {
    int size = 0, sim = 0;
    if(!s1.compare(s2)) {
        return 100;
    } else {
        if(!s2.compare(s1) < 0)
            size = s2.size();
        else
            size = s1.size();

        for(int i = 0; i != (size); ++i) {
            if(s1[i] == s2[i])
                ++sim;
        }
    }
    return sim / ( (s2.size()>s1.size())?s2.size():s1.size() )*100;
}
```

..and now yields 0%...

Comment: `sim/s2.size()` uses integer division and yields `0` always. Even without that, to yield true it needs `sim > s1.size()*s2.size()` and I dont understand how that can ever happen

Comment: after reading it three times (maybe four ;) I think I know what that return is supposed to do. Did you wanted to write `sim /  ( (s2.size()>s1size)?s2.size():s1.size() )` ? note the brackets aroung the ternary. Not 100% sure, but I believe `/` has higher precedence than `>`.

Comment: ...btw returning an `int` doesnt make too much sense. I would either return `sim` directly and let the user calcualte the percentage if needed, or return a `double`

Comment: both s1.size() and s2.size() is 10, and you are returning either one of them * 10....so 100% is expected...

Comment: After all these changes it yelds 0.

Comment: you probably want `return 100 * sim / std::max(s1.size(), s2.size());`

Comment: Yes! It works now! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Break the `return` statement out into multiple statements and log the intermediate values to see where your logic goes wrong.

Comment: I think it will be a pitfall when a string has length > 100 and sim = 1 if you still do integer division

Comment: String length will be never 0. It gets randomized at runtime

Comment: e.g. s1 = 'a', s2 = 'a...a' (1000 'a's), then sim = 1, and you will return 100 / 1000 = 0 in integer division

Comment: 1. 100/1000 = 0.1
2. I've changed return value type to double

Comment: yes the return type is double but when you do the division in sim / std::max(s1.size(), s2.size()), both are integers so it will be an integer division

Comment: So how to protect from that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141959/discussion-between-petar-petrovic-and-joel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to calculate the similarity by using Levenshtein Distance, then you can calculate the similirity based on strings you compare.

**Recursive Java Implementation**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] A = "hello".toCharArray();
    char[] B = "hallo".toCharArray();
    int ld = LD(A, B, A.length, B.length);
    System.out.println(ld);
}

public static int LD(char[] A, char[] B, int n, int m) {
    if (n == 0 && m == 0) return 0;
    if (n == 0) return m;
    if (m == 0) return n;

    return min(
            LD(A, B, n - 1, m - 1) + A[n - 1] == B[m - 1] ? 0 : 1,
            LD(A, B, n, m - 1) + 1,
            LD(A, B, n - 1, m) + 1
    );
}

private static int min(int a, int b, int c) {
    return Math.min(a, Math.min(b, c));
}
```

**C++ based on your code**

```
int similarity(std::string s1, std::string s2) {
    int distance = LD(s1, s2, s1.size(), s2.size());
    return distance / (max(s1.size(), s2.size()));
}

int LD(std::string A, std::string B, int n, int m) {
    if (n == 0 && m == 0) return 0;
    if (n == 0) return m;
    if (m == 0) return n;

    return min(
            LD(A, B, n - 1, m - 1) + A[n - 1] == B[m - 1] ? 0 : 1,
            LD(A, B, n, m - 1) + 1,
            LD(A, B, n - 1, m) + 1
    );
}

int min(int a, int b, int c) {
    return min(a, min(b, c));
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use the function

```
std::string::compare()
```

If you run;

```
if (!s.compare(t)) {
    // 's' and 't' are equal.
}
```

It returns an int:

equal to zero if s and t are equal,

less than zero if s is less than t,

greater than zero if s is greater than t.

To elaborate on the use cases, compare() can be useful if you're interested in how the two strings relate to one another (less or greater) when they happen to be different.

Comment: I've tried to replace my compare routines and it didn't work.